# Firebase functions can't push arabic text

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase functions for a little while but I have stuck at one step that step is when I want to send/push Arabic text the device receive this text as Unreadable text and I couldn't fix the issue till now, so is there any fix for that issue here's my code that I use in functions:

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.n_likes_en = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event =>{

    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;
        
    const language = admin.database().ref(`/users/${user_id}/lang`).once('value');
    
    return language.then(LanguageResult =>{
        
        const Lang_Val = LanguageResult.val();
        
        if (Lang_Val == "ar"){
        
            const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

            return fromUser.then(fromUserResult =>{
        
                const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().uid;
        
                const user_like = fromUserResult.val().describe;
        
                if (user_like == "l"){
            
                    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`/users/${from_user_id}/username`).once('value');        
            
                    return userQuery.then(userResult => {
                
                        const username = userResult.val();
            
                        const device_token = admin.database().ref(`/users/${user_id}/id`).once('value'); 
                
                        return device_token.then(result =>{

                            const token_id = result.val();

                            const payload = {
                                
                                notification:{
                                    
                                    title : "Rankzone",
                            
                                    body : `${username}’ + أعجب بمنشورك`
                                    
                                    icon : "default"}};

                            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response);
                        });
                    });
                }});
        }});
});
```

The problem is the body of the notification it can't be readable when I receive the notification in my device.

Any help guys please.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem by retrieve the Arabic translation or any language you need from the database it self and put it at body of the notification.